# How to find $\ f(6)$ given the following functional equation .

Tags: functional-equations

> Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be a function such that $\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert\le 6\lvert x-y\rvert^2$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$. If $f(3)=6$ then $f(6)$ equals:

how to calculate this ? facing problem with the inequality up there .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**: $f$ is differentiable at all points, and its derivative can be calculated explicitly.

Comment: can u please elaborate?

Comment: @SatyamKumar I have no intention to.

Comment: Is the answer 6 ?

Comment: Thats what i am getting

Comment: @SatyamKumar Indeed.

Comment: Can you suggest some way how to build a strong mathematical background for competitive programming ?

Comment: @SatyamKumar No, I can't.